# How to match all URLs until slash?

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx for matching all of these URLs:

- https://www.domain.tld/service?itm_pm=de:ncp:ctr:c1cn:0:0
- https://www.domain.tld/service
- https://www.domain.tld/service/

But not these one:

- https://www.domain.tld/service/afdsasdaf
- https://www.domain.tld/service/afdsasdaf/asdasd

I tried it with
https://www.domain.tld/service[^/]*
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mark the end of the string

Summary of changes:

- I would work with a `$` delimiter for "end of string"
- A `/` usually needs to be escaped. This may be different based on your settings/language etc.
- The `.` must be escaped as well, otherwise `wwwwdomain.tld` would be found

Let's use this one:

**Solution with working example:**

```regex
https:\/\/www\.domain\.tld\/service[^\/]*\/?$
```

You can play around with it here:
https://regex101.com/r/wm6Nit/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow `https://www.domain.tld/service/` specifically, do that explicitly:

`https://www.domain.tld/service(/?|[^/]*)$`